# Get value from join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm starting out with Rails (version 5.1.7) and am having some trouble getting my head around the `has_many :through` associations, specifically how to retrieve values from the intermediary join model.

So I have the following models:

```
#app/models/project.rb
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
  has_many :project_users
  has_many :users, through: :project_users
end

#app/models/project_user.rb
class ProjectUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_users
  has_many :projects, through: :project_users
  has_many :projects, inverse_of: 'owner'
end
```

The requirements are:

- multiple projects and multiple users, with a many-to-many relationship between them;
- the relationship needs specific attributes (role, hourly fee, etc), which is why I didn't opt for a HABTM;
- each project needs to have a single owner;
- both `users` and `owner` are items derived from the User model (and a single user may at the same time be a project 'user' and 'owner').

Now here's my database:

```
#db/schema.rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20210409064744) do

  create_table "project_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "project_id"
    t.string "role"
    t.decimal "fee", precision: 10, scale: 2
    t.index ["project_id"], name: "index_project_users_on_project_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_project_users_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_projects_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "login"
    t.string "firstname"
    t.string "lastname"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "avatar"
    t.string "role"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

I have no trouble getting values like `<%= @project.name %>` or

```
<strong>Project members:</strong>
  <ul>
    <% @project.users.each do |proj_user| %>
    <li><%= link_to proj_user.name, user_path(proj_user) %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

in my `app/views/projects/show.html.erb`.

But how in the world can I get the user's fee for said project? Specifically, how can I retrieve the value of `fee` from the `project_users` table?

For clarity, here's the `project_users` table.

| id | created_at | updated_at | user_id | project_id | role | fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-04-09 06:54:21.231836 | 2021-04-09 06:54:21.231836 | 2 | 1 | member | 300 |
| 2 | 2021-04-09 06:54:21.233715 | 2021-04-09 06:54:21.233715 | 3 | 1 | member | 300 |
| 3 | 2021-04-09 06:54:21.251290 | 2021-04-09 06:54:21.251290 | 2 | 2 | member | 300 |
| 4 | 2021-04-09 06:54:21.254056 | 2021-04-09 06:54:21.254056 | 3 | 2 | member | 250 |
| 5 | 2021-04-09 06:54:21.273320 | 2021-04-09 06:54:21.273320 | 5 | 3 | member | 300 |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably better here to change your iteration to iterate through `project_users` and not `users` then call `users` from `project_users` since it has all the info

```
    <% @project.project_users.each do |proj_user| %>
      <li><%= link_to proj_user.user.name, user_path(proj_user.user) %></li>
    <% end %>
```

then you will be able to call `proj_user.fee` directly

you can also delegate user_name to project_user model like so if you want

```rb
class ProjectUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project

  delegate :name, to: :user, prefix: true
end
```

so it would become:

```
    <% @project. project_users.each do |proj_user| %>
      <li><%= link_to proj_user.user_name, user_path(proj_user.user) %></li>
    <% end %>
```

you can read more about delegate here https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate

Comment: You might want to do some eager loading also, with e.g. `@project.includes(:users)` to avoid N+1 queries

Comment: Yeah, it works! Just for the record, the code to retrieve the fee is `<%= proj_user.fee %>`.

With regard to the name delegation, my User model already includes the following method:
`def name
    "#{firstname} #{lastname}"
end
`
which is satisfactory.